# Can we configure Keycloak Multiple Password Policies for User Groups/Different Users into single realm?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am having a project and its keycloak client, have created multiple users with multiple roles. Now I have a requirement to assign multiple password policies on basis of role. Is it configurable? If It is then how?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to configure the password policies in the keycloak. The below URL path is where the policies can be configured http://host:8080/auth/admin/master/console/#/realms/master/authentication/password-policy

Please refer the below link for more info
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_admin/topics/authentication/password-policies.adoc

Comment: this does not answer the question